# Imagem de fundo faz a página piscar ao ser carregada

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estou criando um site, ao carregar qualquer uma das 6 páginas de uma categoria do site que possuem cada uma delas uma imagem de fundo com média de 40 a 70kb, a área onde se encontra a imagem pisca. A página pisca sempre ao clicar na página ou atualizá-la, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Você consegue compartilhar um exemplo para entendermos melhor o problema?

Comment: "o que posso fazer": não usar caps lock nem bold pra tentar chamar a atenção... Mas focando no problema, você tentou alguma coisa? Com CSS ou JS? Tipo `display:none` e fade-in quando carrega? . . . Ah, sim, **[edit]e** a pergunta pra adicionar detalhes. E bem vindo ao [pt.so] ;)

Comment: Não vi nada de errado... :) [Chrome no Ubuntu 14]

Comment: Rui repare que a página pisca na área onde esta a imagem de funda da categoria, ela pisca ao atualizar a página.

Comment: Acho que vou usar o sistema de compressão do base 64 vai ser o jeito !

Answer (score 4):

A imagem em si não está a piscar, o que acontece é que devido ao elevado numero de *requests* que a tua página obriga a serem feitos, existe uma pequena demora entre o tempo em que a página é servida e os conteúdos chegam, mais propriamente a imagem.

A demora é pequena o suficiente para causar a impressão de estar a piscar, mas não é o caso.

Se tiveres uma ligação lenta vais poder observar que efectivamente a página é servida com uma zona a branco onde deveria estar a imagem e pouco depois aparece a mesma.

## Solução

Reduz o número de pedidos que estás a fazer quer a nível de *scripts*, quer a nível de estilos quer a nível de imagens:

1. #### CSS

   Todos os ficheiros de CSS podem ser descarregados num único pedido por parte do navegador:

   **Exemplo em PHP**

   ```php
   <?php
   header('Content-type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');

   ob_start("compress");

   function compress($buffer) {

     /* remove comentários */
     $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);

     /* remove tabulaçõess, espaços, quebras de linhas */
     $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);

     return $buffer;
   }

   $cssFiles = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/*.css';

   foreach(glob($cssFiles) as $file) {
     include($file);
   }

   ob_end_flush();
   ?>
   ```

   Com o exemplo em cima, podes ter um ficheiro PHP dentro da tua pasta onde tens os diversos CSS e ao invés de chamares todos os `.CSS` no site, chamas apenas o ficheiro PHP:

   ```html
   <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://meusite.com/css/css.php">
   ```

   > Para o teu caso em particular, passas 4 pedidos para 1 só.
2. #### JS

   O exemplo dado para o CSS pode ser também aplicado aos ficheiros de *script*:

   **Exemplo em PHP**

   ```php
   <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

   ob_start();

   $files = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/*.js';

   foreach(glob($files) as $file) {
     include($file);
   }

   ob_end_flush();
   ?>
   ```

   Com o exemplo em cima, podes ter um ficheiro PHP dentro da tua pasta onde tens os diversos *scripts* e ao invés de chamares todos os `.JS` no site, chamas apenas o ficheiro PHP:

   ```html
   <script src="http://meusite.com/js/js.php" type="text/javascript">
   ```

   > Para o teu caso em particular, passas 4 pedidos para 1 só.
3. #### Imagens

   Tens muitas imagens a serem apresentadas na mesma página, mas isso não quer dizer que tenham que ser ficheiros distintos.

   Fazendo uso de CSS sprites, podes ter uma imagem composta por várias imagens pequenas que são posteriormente posicionadas no local adequado através de CSS.

   A título de exemplo, esta tua parte do cabeçalho:

   [image: Imagens Actuais]

   Poderia ser um único ficheiro:

   [image: CSS Sprites]

   [Um dos muitos sites](http://csssprites.com/) que gera este tipo de imagens de forma a que não tenhas grande trabalho.

   > Para o teu caso em particular, passas 8 pedidos para 1 só.
4. #### CDNs

   Podes fazer uso de [CDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) para aumentar o número de pedidos (*requests*) simultâneos que os navegadores fazem dado que o limite mais baixo e que está a afectar a tua página é o limite imposto ao número de ficheiros descarregados em simultâneo por cada endereço.

   Exemplo de CDN para o Twitter Bootstrap que estás a utilizar:

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```

   Com esse endereço, o CSS base para o Twitter Bootstrap pode ser descarregado em simultâneo com outros ficheiros do servidor onde se encontra o teu web-site, acelerando assim todo o processo de carregamento da página.

---

Com as dicas em cima apresentadas estarás a:

- Reduzir o número de pedidos actualmente em 37 para 24;
- Comprimir o CSS contribuindo assim para um carregamento mais eficaz da página;
- O navegador faz download de mais ficheiros em simultâneo o que vai permitir um tempo de disponibilidade da página mais baixo;
- Acabar o piscar da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

O que esta ocorrendo é normal. Você esta fazendo uma requisição e toda a página é enviada e toda uma página é retornada. O ideal é usar chamadas Ajax e enviar e receber apenas o necessário. Background por exemplo não seria alterado, portanto, não "piscaria".